# How to do simple function operations in django and return values to the admin interface?

Tags: python, django

I am making my first steps in django and python. What I do not understand is where should I place my main functions and how to control the output of them.

For example, I am trying to make some calculations with django:

```
class Calc(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100), 
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to write a method to check the status variable:

```
def checkStatus():
    if self.status == 'completed':
        ....... #set Calc.text = 'task is completed'
    elif self.status == 'pending':
        ....... #set Calc.text = 'task is pending'
return # what should I return here?

checkStatus = checkStatus()
```

Then, I want to display it on the admin interface, anywhere:

```
<span>task status: {{ checkstatus }}</span>
```

Can someone give me a tip on how do I do something so simple like this? In any PHP mvc, the view is rendered from the controller and variables are passed to the view as contexts. But how about django? What am I missing ?

Comment: You would do `obj.checkstatus`. It is _not_ a good idea to mix updating the model field, if you mean to do a read only

Comment: Where in the admin do you want to display it? For example, displaying values in the change list is easy, while displaying the value 'anywhere in the admin' is another story

Comment: Bear in mind the admin is a specific Django app: "how to display method results in Django" is not the same question as "how to display method results in the Django admin".

Comment: @sk1p in the base_html.html which I am changing right now

Comment: @karthikr I am not indenting to update the model, I just don't know where to put and how to call my functions

Comment: @RobDel I can see you know the **where** now you must search the **how**. I  think what you need is a custom template tag for **checkstatus** thing. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: @karthikr my second thought was to iterate through all results in the views.py and save them on a list. Then do the calculations inside an action and return the list. But what about the Django admin? it doesn't have something to do with views.py as it carries its own files

Comment: @RaydelMiranda what about the Calc.text thing ? I mean, its value should be fetched from the db but If the conditions exist, I should be able to change that.

Comment: If you want to display it everywhere in the admin, on every page, you first need to think about which object you want to display. All `Calc` instances? Just some? And then you could write a template tag to fetch those you want

Comment: @sk1p this is not the point. My question is how and where should I place my functions ?

Comment: @RobDel Well, about the Calc.text thing: You can put that function as a function member of Calc form without any problem, just as a normal python class.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda can you please give me an example ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#models.py
class Calc(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100), 
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    @property
    def checkStatus():
      return 'xxx'

#views.py
from django.views.generic import DetailView,
  class Calc(DetailView):
     model = Calc

#template
{{ object.checkStatus }}
```